# How to ignore all dist folders except the one?

Tags: git, gitignore

we do have a few folders in our projects called `dist`. These shall be ignored by git. On the other hands just putting `dist/` into the `.gitignore` file does have side effects when using bower, since the dist folders within `bower_components/` are ignored as well.

Any suggestions on how to correctly define a rule, that ignore `dist` folders except the ones within `bower_components`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Sure:

```
dist/
!bower_components/**/dist/
```

Comment: Does this work recursively in all directories to ignore dist ?

Comment: Yes it does. The first line basically states 'ignore all folders called `dist`'. The second line overrides this rule for the given path